# Как изменить цвет текста placeholder

Tags: css, вёрстка

```
<textarea name="Comment" placeholder="Введите текст комментария"></textarea>
```

Как поменять цвет "Введите текст комментария"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как поменять цвет "Введите текст комментария"

Например так...

```css
::placeholder {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="Comment" placeholder="Введите текст комментария"></textarea>
```

Comment: @j3nty в такому случае примите ответ, иначе вас вряд ли будут помогать в будущем